# How many arrangements of the integers 1,2, .., n such that from (ALAN TUCKER Applied Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

I was solving a question from alan tucker's applied combinatorial book and got stuck at this question: 
How many arrangements of the integers 1,2, .., n are there such that each integer differ by one(except the first) from some integer to the left of it in the arrangement?
pg 202 section 5.2 problem 76.
Please tell how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider such an arrangement $k_1,k_2,\ldots,k_n$. Let $i_1<i_2<\ldots<i_r$ denote the indices in $\{2,\ldots,n\}$ so that $k_{i_\ell}>k_1$, and let $j_1<j_2<\ldots<j_s$ denote the indices so that $k_{j_\ell}<k_1$. (So $r+s=n-1$.) Now your condition means that $k_{i_\ell} = k_1+\ell$ and $k_{j_\ell}=k_j-\ell$. So the number of sequences for a given $k_1$ is the number of ways of interleaving the increasing sequence $k_1+1,k_1+2,\ldots,n$ (which has $n-k_1$ terms) and the decreasing sequence $k_1-1,k_1-2,\ldots,1$ (which has $k_1-1$ terms), which is $\binom{n-1}{k_1-1}$. So the total number of sequences is $\sum_{k_1=1}^n\binom{n-1}{k_1-1}=\sum_{t=0}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}{t}=2^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 0):

For each integer to differ by 1, they must be either increasing or decreasing. There are $n$ locations to put your first number (say 1). Then go from ther

(Edit: I misunderstood, I read "each integer differs from the to the left of it by 1")

Comment: thanks for answering,
"there are n locations to put your first number..." if you put 1 at last position then how come there are two positions to put 2 .. i think there are n-1 positions. Moreover sequence 2,3,1,4 is a valid sequence(isn't it?).  2 is at first position so ignored, 3 has 2 on it's left , 1 has 2 on it's left, 4 has 3 on it's left.